# Shorcut StandardKey.PreviousChild not working on linux

Tags: linux, qt, qml, qtquick2

I'm trying the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> shortcut, and it's not working. Qt 5.7 on Linux. A simple example showing the issue:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Shortcut {
        sequence: StandardKey.PreviousChild
        onActivated: {
            console.log("prev child")
        }
    }

    Shortcut {
        sequence: StandardKey.NextChild
        onActivated: {
            console.log("next child")
        }
    }

}
```

Is there something I've done wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have done nothing wrong. It does not work for me either. I read this http://doc-snapshots.qt.io/qt5-5.7/qkeysequence.html#keyboard-layout-issues but still can not resolve it.

I can not find the short cut keys combination for `Ctrl+Shift+Tab` on my global keyboard settings either.

The following hack works on my end when I directly hard code the shortcut keys sequence `sequence: "Ctrl+Shift+Tab"` like below.

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Controls 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.0

ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    // Does not work
    Shortcut {
        sequence: StandardKey.PreviousChild
        onActivated: {
            console.log("prev child")
        }
    }

    // Works but it is a hack
    Shortcut {
        sequence: "Ctrl+Shift+Tab"
        onActivated: {
            console.log("hard coded pre child")
        }
    }

    Shortcut {
        sequence: StandardKey.NextChild
        onActivated: {
            console.log("next child")
        }
    }
}
```